# Blender stops responding when importing/exporting images

Tags: export, import

I'm using blender on a mac. It's working fine otherwise. But when importing/exporting images, for example to place a background image or texture a model with an image, it will stop responding after press "import" (after the image has been selected from my files if you know what I mean). This only happens occasionally, I force quit and when trying the same thing, it works the second time after the crash.

Comment: What format is the image? How large? How much RAM is there on the computer? Are you dragging the image or are you opening using the image as background or on the UV/Image editor? What version of Blender are you using>

Comment: i'm trying with a jpeg that's 210Kb. . my mac is this: [https://support.apple.com/kb/SP719?locale=en_CA&viewlocale=en_US], I'm just importing using blender's feature, not dragging it in. dragging the image into the UV editor works however. my blender is 2.79.